# Does opencv gpu functions scale up depending upon the number of cores on the gpu?

Tags: opencv, gpu, opticalflow

I am new to CUDA and having some problem with executing GPU version of farneback optical flow. I was recently using gpu version of farneback optical flow provided in opencv for one of my application of action recognition in videos. I executed the farneback optical flow (GPU Version) for one of the sample video, and it took around 12 seconds to calculate the optical flow on NVidea Geforce Gpu with 96 cores.

However the same code I am trying to run it on a more advanced GPU (TitanX) which has around 3072 cores but I don't know why it is taking almost the same time to compute the optical flow as it used to take for NVidea Geforce Gpu. Would it be possible that my code has some flaws or is it possible that the function itself is allocating limited number of cores for the program to execute irrespective of the GPU? Can I have the access on the number of threads a function can allocate to the GPU so that I can manually set the number of threads in order to speed up the code for a more advanced GPU. The cuda file of farneback optical flow have some code lines such as **dim3 block(128)** which allocate some block size to the GPU. Would my program run fast if I try to increase the block size from 128 to 256? I tried it but it is showing some error like **OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (invalid device function) in call, file /home/aditya-vision/opencv-2.4.9/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/device/detail/transform_detail.hpp**. Kindly help me through this by giving your valuable suggestions.

I am also posting the nvprof output through which I visualized the bootlenecks in the code. Kindly give your suggestions based on that.

```
==10935== NVPROF is profiling process 10935, command: ./farneback_flow resizeVideo.avi 
It took 14 second(s). 
==10935== Profiling application: ./farneback_flow resizeVideo.avi
==10935== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
62.38%  543.05ms      9870  55.020us  23.265us  263.63us cv::gpu::device::optflow_farneback::boxFilter5(int, int, cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>, int, float, cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>)
17.11%  148.94ms      9870  15.090us  5.9840us  58.978us  cv::gpu::device::optflow_farneback::updateMatrices(int, int, cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>, cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>,cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>, cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>, cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>)
5.12%  44.550ms      1974  22.568us  15.328us  41.090us  void cv::gpu::device::optflow_farneback::gaussianBlur<cv::gpu::device::BrdReflect101<float>>(int, int, cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>, int, float, cv::gpu::PtrStep)
5.07%  44.137ms      9870  4.4710us  2.7200us  16.225us  cv::gpu::device::optflow_farneback::updateFlow(int, int, cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>, cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>, cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>)
3.72%  32.371ms       658  49.196us  48.898us  53.090us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
3.05%  26.517ms      1974  13.433us  5.9200us  31.265us  void cv::gpu::device::optflow_farneback::polynomialExpansion<int=5>(int, int, cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>, cv::gpu::PtrStep)
1.58%  13.744ms      4277  3.2130us     928ns  17.601us  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
0.96%  8.3349ms      2632  3.1660us  2.0800us  5.7610us  void cv::gpu::device::resize_linear<float>(cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<float>, float, float, float)
0.38%  3.3082ms       658  5.0270us  4.4480us  6.4960us  [CUDA memcpy DtoD]
0.36%  3.1376ms      1316  2.3840us  1.4400us  3.5840us  void cv::gpu::device::transform_detail::transformSmart<float, float, cv::gpu::device::Convertor<float, float, float>, cv::gpu::device::WithOutMask>(cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<float>, cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>, float, float)
0.20%  1.7484ms       658  2.6570us  1.8880us  5.4720us  void cv::gpu::device::transform_detail::transformSmart<unsigned char, float, cv::gpu::device::Convertor<unsigned char, float, float>, cv::gpu::device::WithOutMask>(cv::gpu::PtrStepSz<unsigned char>, cv::gpu::PtrStep<float>, float, unsigned char)
0.08%  707.22us       658  1.0740us     864ns  1.8240us  [CUDA memset]

==10935== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
92.17%  12.7227s      1342  9.4804ms  4.1420us  12.6725s  cudaMallocPitch
3.96%  547.18ms      1342  407.74us  3.5120us  1.7912ms  cudaFree
1.47%  202.25ms     38164  5.2990us  4.1290us  266.19us  cudaLaunch
0.87%  120.66ms     41783  2.8870us     579ns  268.98us  cudaStreamSynchronize
0.55%  75.686ms      1974  38.341us  6.9130us  113.53us  cudaMemcpy2D
0.28%  38.270ms    215824     177ns     144ns  264.85us  cudaSetupArgument
0.27%  36.972ms      1316  28.093us  9.7560us  44.813us  cudaDeviceSynchronize
0.20%  27.309ms      3619  7.5460us  5.6390us  35.784us  cudaMemcpyToSymbol
0.06%  8.2456ms     38164     216ns     159ns  264.80us  cudaGetLastError
0.06%  7.6159ms     38164     199ns     158ns  229.11us  cudaConfigureCall
0.05%  6.2155ms       658  9.4460us  5.0870us  36.748us  cudaMemset2DAsync
0.04%  4.8575ms      9871     492ns     353ns  260.80us  cudaGetDevice
0.01%  2.0688ms      1645  1.2570us     894ns  7.9890us  cudaStreamDestroy
0.01%  1.6704ms      1645  1.0150us     493ns  133.13us  cudaStreamCreate
0.01%  802.14us        83  9.6640us     590ns  349.30us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
0.00%  645.00us         1  645.00us  645.00us  645.00us  cudaGetDeviceProperties
0.00%  558.01us      3948     141ns     106ns     303ns  cudaSetDoubleForDevice
0.00%  90.543us         1  90.543us  90.543us  90.543us  cuDeviceTotalMem
0.00%  63.614us         1  63.614us  63.614us  63.614us  cuDeviceGetName
0.00%  3.3740us         2  1.6870us  1.0400us  2.3340us  cuDeviceGetCount
0.00%  1.6930us         2     846ns     773ns     920ns  cuDeviceGet
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible for GPU functions in general, including OpenCV GPU functions, to "scale up" when they run on GPUs with more cores.  If you're not witnessing any speed difference between a very slow and a very fast GPU, it's probably the case that the GPU portion of the work is not the bottleneck.  In general, using OpenCV GPU functions, it's not expected, nor appropriate, for you to set the block size.  The "invalid device function" error is probably arising out of how you compiled OpenCV, not anything to do with your specific code change.  It's always possible that your code has flaws.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have posted the nvprof output of my code. And it seems that 92% of the time is consumed in the API calls of some cudaMallocPitch function. Could you give any suggestion how can I overcome this bottleneck?

Comment: There is a single `cudaMallocPitch` call (the `Max`) that is taking 12.6725s. This is probably absorbing CUDA start up time, and there is not much you can do about that. I'm not sure why the start up time should be that long, but it is likely a combination of factors like system configuration and CUDA libraries linked into the code. This start-up time is something you should only incur once per application execution, so if you benchmark your process by running it once without timing, then running it once with timing measurement, I think you will probably find the 2nd execution is much shorter.

Comment: So basically what you mean to say is that if I run the code for the first time it shall take much more time than if I run the same code second time or third time as cuda is taking more time to start?

Comment: The very first `cudaMallocPitch` call is costing you 12 seconds.  After that, everything is fast.  If you stop the app, and re-run the app, then the first `cudaMallocPitch` call will probably cost you 12 seconds, again. If you do a lot of work in your app (so that it takes much more than 12 seconds to run) then the cost of the 12 second startup should not be an issue - you are amortizing it over the remainder of the work you are doing.  But if the only thing you want to do takes less than 12 seconds total, then this is probably not a good approach.

Comment: Okay got it so basically what you are trying to say is that if I try to run the code for a more longer application then this loss can be neglected? As the video that I am giving as input has 330 frames if I take a longer video say example 1000 frames then this loss should be negligible? However when I am trying to run the code on my laptop with Nvidea Geforce GPU such bottleneck in cudaMallocPitch is not appearing and everything seems to be uniformly distributed in the timeline. What would be the cause of such problem on Titan x?